# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when sending info to other js file

Tags: json, node.js, request

I'm trying to make a chat bot, but I'm getting a error when I try to send data to another js file.

```
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at Request.request.get [as _callback] (D:\Projects\NodeJS\WoWBot-Discord\lib\user.js:12:27)
at self.callback (D:\Projects\NodeJS\WoWBot-Discord\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Request.onRequestError (D:\Projects\NodeJS\WoWBot-Discord\node_modules\request\request.js:878:8)    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

This is the bot.js file that I have. Here is where all the commands will be placed.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const realms = require('./lib/realms');
const user = require('./lib/user');
const guild = require('./lib/guild');
const race = require('./lib/race');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online');
    client.user.setStatus('online');
    client.user.setGame('In progress');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    var msg = message.content.split(' ');
    switch (msg[0]) {
        case ("player"):
            let country = msg[1];
            let realm = msg[2];
            let pname = msg[3];
            user.characterProfile(country, realm, pname);
        break;
    }
});

client.login('');
```

But I am trying to get the data from a other js file, because I don't want it to be a cluster of code mixed together.

This is the file user.js. In here I will get the specific data from a api url.

```
const request = require('request');

function characterProfile(country, realm, uname) {
    request.get(`https://${country}.api.battle.netwow/character/${realm}/${uname}?locale=en_US&apikey=4p7ha7t5udqa7fgmpasm9xhb6a9vmm9u`, (err, res, body) => {
        const test = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(test.name);
    });
}

exports.characterProfile = characterProfile;
```

1 thing that I noticed is when I change the request.get url to a normal link without for example ${country} added into it, the result will pe printed fine without any errors.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: body is undefined.  Try debugging your url interpolation first, but checking to make sure body is valid would help too.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Thanks for the tip. I debugged the url interpolation and noticed that something was wrong with fetching data from the url. this also caused the body to be invalid.